# How to Create a Setup Installer for a WPF C# Application to Allow Users to Choose Installation Directory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, deployment

I am looking for assistance in deploying my WPF c# application. I have developed a small application and would like to make it available for the other users. Currently, I have been publishing below way

[image]

But I would like to create the setup like other software applications.
This setup file should allow users to install the tool in the directory of their choice. Do you have any ideas or suggestions on how I can generate such a setup file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Programs such as Innosetup or Squirrel, these programs help You to create an installer customized.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom MSI installer in Visual Studio as explained [here](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/create-msi-installer-with-visual-studio.html) and [here](https://blog.jam-es.com/2019/12/generating-msi-installer-for-wpf.html).